# R: parse and evaluate variable names within a function

Tags: r, parsing, for-loop, eval, updatemodel

I have a rather huge set of predictors to do a model-selection on, for the sake of simplicity this example will however work with the `mtcars` dataset.
I am somewhat reluctant to take the `dredge()`-approach, since I want to increase my awareness over which predictors are being chosen and why.

I wrote a function to go through all predictors (via `update()`) for one step of selection to be able to evaluate their effect size (estimate) and p-value. The output is supposed to be a data.frame where I can see everything rather quickly.

It seems kind of awkward to me. When running the for-loop - after defining `model` and `variables` (and everything around it) manually - everything seems to be fine and the expected output (see below) is produced. When running the function, `update/eval/parse` does not seem to recognize that `variables` has been defined and is thus not able to compute the updated model.

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Any suggestions to improve the code beyond that?

**function body**

```
find_effects <- function(model, variables=NULL){
  require(car)
  estim <- NULL; p_val <- NULL; stars <- NULL; names <- NULL

  for(i in 1:length(variables)){
    original <- model
    if(is.null(variables)){
      cat("'variables' is NULL")
    } else {
      cat(paste("'variables' is not NULL, it has ", length(variables), " elements"))
    }
    updated <- update(model, . ~ . + eval(parse(text=variables[i])))
    if(length(rownames(summary(original)$coef))==length(rownames(summary(updated)$coef))){
      next
    }
    df.summary <- data.frame(estim=summary(updated)$coef[,1], names=rownames(summary(updated)$coef))
    df.Anova <- data.frame(p_val=Anova(updated, type="III")[,3], names=rownames(Anova(updated, type="III")))
    estim <- c(estim, df.summary$estim[df.summary$names=="eval(parse(text = variables[i]))"])
    p_val <- c(p_val, df.Anova$p_val[df.Anova$names=="eval(parse(text = variables[i]))"])
    stars <- symnum(p_val, corr = FALSE,
                    cutpoints = c(0, .001, .01, .05, .1, 1),
                    symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
    names <- c(names, variables[i])

  }
  df <- noquote(cbind(Estimate=format(estim), "Pr(>Chisq)"=format(p_val), " "=stars))
  rownames(df) <- names
  return(df)

}

library(lme4)
mpgs <- lmer(mpg ~ hp + (1|cyl), data=mtcars, REML=F)

find_effects(mpgs, colnames(mtcars[c(3, 5:11)]))
```

**expected output**

```
         Estimate    Pr(>Chisq)      
    disp -0.02942650 7.331371e-05 ***
    drat  4.69815776 3.449956e-05 ***
    wt   -3.78335019 4.098811e-10 ***
    qsec -0.98805796 1.505408e-02 *  
    vs    0.04636047 9.798979e-01    
    am    5.00527293 1.506875e-06 ***
    gear  3.08916264 5.346748e-05 ***
    carb  0.33074245 6.094443e-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the formula for the update when you call the function will be something like this:

```
mpg ~ hp + (1|cyl) + eval(parse(text = variables[i]))
```

The expression is evaluated only after being passed to the update function, where the variables object is not defined. Hence the error.

create the formula and then pass it to the update function.

```
updated <- paste(". ~ . + ", variables[i], sep="")
updated <- update(model, updated)
```

Comment: thanks. this works for me. However, it does not explain why running the for-loop manually works, while wrapping it into the function results in a non-working function...

Comment: my guess would be the change in environment when you call a function within a function. when you run it manually, the eval is called in the update function, it has access to the global environment where 'variables' is defined, whereas when it is called inside a function, the eval doesn't have access to the environment where the variables is defined..... read about R environments to know more..